# Is it possible to determine the visibleLines() value of a multipicklist programmatically?

Tags: metadata-api, metadata, describesobject, multi-select, describefieldresult

For a multipicklist, the visibleLines attribute value is not available from internal Schema.DescribeFieldResult.class. Is there any other way to determine what this value is for a field programmatically?
I would need to determine the value of the visibleLines field for existing multipicklists, not create multiPicklists with the value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This `visibleLines` attribute is available via the CustomField in the [Tooling API](https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/sfdc/pdf/api_tooling.pdf). I don't think there is any direct Apex API.

If you want to access it from e.g. Java, then you can generate the Java code from the WSDL available in the API section of Setup in any org.

If you want to access it from Apex, then this [apex-toolingapi](https://github.com/afawcett/apex-toolingapi) open source project might be the best place to start. See blog posts linked from that project - potentially you only need a few lines of Apex code to access the information.

Comment: Just as a side note, the number of visible lines can be discerned from a multi picklist precision value in getDescribe(). Here is an example: Account.Multiple_Picklist__c.getDescribe(); (I had to update my api version to get this working: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/16914/schema-getglobaldescribe-and-invalid-field-lastreferenceddate-for-account), but I think the tooling api is almost a more correct answer. I am glad you pointed me to the resource, which could have definitely solved the issue, and will most likely solve a lot of other questions surrounding metadata for me.

Comment: @amandafouts The describe API is much more convenient as it does not involve a web service call and so can be used anywhere. But I'm surprised as the [getPrecision](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_fields_describe.htm#apex_Schema_DescribeFieldResult_getPrecision) documentation doesn't mention that and it would be a pretty poor design to make that getter represent two different things.